# Detecting internet and saving to internal storage in that case in Android using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, storage, internal

I'm making an app in Android Studio that connects to a database and sends a report to it with a POST request with PHP.

What I want to achieve is that when the device doesn't have internet I want the report to save to an internal file and when it detects internet connection it automatically sends it.

My problem is that I use an array with each report and I want an array that contains arrays, and to be sent separately to the database, which I have no idea how to make that. I know how to send a single file every time and with internet, but to save it to an internal file and send them separately and then remove the internal file. I think it would make sense to use a for loop.

If someone could help me, it'd be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about persisting data on device, there are multiple ways to do what you intended.

- First & foremost is that you store your local data not in file but in [database (SQLITE)](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)
- Then you need to form and data structure for sending data. [JSON](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) would be best, because is simple to ready and easy
- After that, you need a strategy on how to check the internet connection on time interval, for that a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) would do a job, which checks for internet connection on multiple time intervals.

P.S. There are many good and more robust ways to do this, the is what I think is best for your implementation.